# How to upload a file through ajax in struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

```
<s:file name="excel" id="excel"/> 
function saveData(){ 
    vald();             
    var postData = $("#fname").serializeArray();            
    $("#fname")[0].reset();             
    $('<div class="success-tog" >Processing...</div>').prependTo('body').delay(1000); 
    $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "",data: postData success: sucFunc()}); 

Script Code

}
```

Comment: This is NOT a proper question. This is not even a question, is just a bunch of malformed (and unformatted, until my edit) code. Please edit your question, describe exactly what you want, what have you tried, what doesn't work, and the specific point where you're stuck and need help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use formdata to uplaod code or any jquery file upload plugin
https://stackoverflow.com/a/204271/876739

You can see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41458116/876739

```js
$(document).on('click', '#upload', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      var fd = new FormData();
      var file = $('#my_file')[0].files[0];
      fd.append('file', file);
      fd.append('userId', $('#userid').val());
      console.log("hi");
      $.ajax({
          url: 'UploadPic',
          data: fd,
          type: "POST",
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(dd) {
            alert("sucessfully Uploaded")
            }
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="my_file">
<input type="hidden" id="userid" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
```